# iOS AppStore Review rules and libotr.a + libcrypt.a

Tags: ios, app-store, off-the-record-messaging

I plan to build safe chatting app. For this purpose I plan to use libotr.a and libcrypt.a libraries. But I feel that using of this libraries contradicts the rules of AppStore ([link](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.otr.devel/1259)).

Can you confirm or disprove my concerns?

Comment: Is the concern about the GPL/LGPL? What are the licenses on libotr.a and libcrypt.a? What is the specific concern?

Comment: If you use another persons copyrighted code (or property in general) other than as specifically allowed that is theft regardless of Apple's rules. Either just abide by the rules or don't use it, it is that simple.